# Shopify app oauth redirect_uri incorrect format after deployed on fly.io

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I have written a very simply Shopify app based on the latest template and I did not touch any part about the OAuth, and the app installed and worked just fine when I run in dev mode. After I deploy it on fly.io, when I try to install it, the `redirect_uri` in the OAuth url becomes `redirect_uri=little-haze-0000.fly.dev://little-haze-0000.fly.dev/api/auth/callback`, and it gave an error "Oauth error invalid_request: The redirect_uri is not whitelisted" (of course it is wrong!).

Obviously there should be a `https` in front of the `://`. I manually change the parameter to `redirect_uri=https://little-haze-0000.fly.dev/api/auth/callback` and the app can be successfully installed. I looked through the code and app setting in my partner account and can't find anywhere I can modify the `redirect_uri`. I wonder where I did wrong?